# Can I generate polygons based on which of a series of points each part of the map is closest to?

Tags: qgis, polygon, point

If I have 10 points in a shape file, I'd like to create a new shapefile of polygons around each individual point that represents the area of the map where that point is the closest one.  For example if it was cell towers, it would show each area that is optimally served by each tower.

Comment: have you tried the voronoi polygons processing script?

Comment: Yep that's spot on thanks!